# xmlEventParse returns empty dataframe

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing

I am new to XML, and I know that when working with big files, it is best to use xmlEventParse() and getNodeSet() in R. But then, my code runs endlesly, and I do not know why. Perhaps improper defining of paths?

A dummy XML file that looks like the original file can be found on this link:
[dummy xml file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0MjygvBH6bsdjl4dTRLazBISWM/view?usp=sharing)

And my dummy R code is a thus:

```
library(XML)

FOOid_traverse <- function() {

uids <- c() 
refs <- c()

REC <- function(x) {

uid <- xpathSApply(x, "//N8:EntityList/N8:Entity/N2:OrganisationName", 
xmlValue)
ref <- xpathSApply(x,   "//N8:EntityList/N8:Entity/N5:Identifiers/N5:Identifier/N5:IdentifierElement", xmlValue)

if (length(uid) > 0) {

  if (length(ref) == 0) {

    uids <<- c(uids, uid)
    refs <<- c(refs, NA_character_)

  } else {

    uids <<- c(uids, rep(uid, length(ref)))
    refs <<- c(refs, ref)

  } 

 } 

}


list(
REC = REC, 
FOOid_df = function() { 
  data.frame(uid = uids, ref = refs, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
```

)

}

FOOid_f <- FOOid_traverse()

invisible(
  xmlEventParse(
    file = path.expand("companies_xml_extract_20170703.xml"), 
    branches = FOOid_f["REC"])
  )

FOOid_f$FOOid_df()

Thanks

Comment: can you pls explain your expectation in plain words?

Comment: I expect a dataframe that has OrganisationName & IdentifierElement as column heads. In other words, I expect to extract data stored in       "N8:EntityList/N8:Entity/N2:OrganisationName" and "N8:EntityList/N8:Entity/N5:Identifiers/N5:Identifier/N5:IdentifierElement" paths

Comment: Isn't the xml incomplete? You may need to correct it in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
xml_doc <- read_xml("test.xml")

OrganisationName <- xml_doc %>% 
  xml_find_all("//N2:OrganisationName/N2:NameElement", ns=xml_ns(xml_doc)) %>% 
  xml_text()
IdentifierElement <- xml_doc %>% 
  xml_find_all("//N5:Identifiers/N5:Identifier/N5:IdentifierElement", ns=xml_ns(xml_doc)) %>% 
  xml_text()
df <- data.frame(OrganisationName, IdentifierElement)
df
```

*Don't forget to let us know if it solved your problem :)*